# Druid SQL: filter on result of expression

Tags: druid

I have HTTP access log data in a Druid data source, and I want to see access patterns based on certain identifiers in the URL path. I wrote this query, and it works fine:

```sql
select regexp_extract(path, '/id/+([0-9]+)', 1) as "id",
       sum("count") as "request_count"
  from "access-logs"
  where __time >= timestamp '2022-01-01'
  group by 1
```

The only problem is that not all requests match that pattern, so I get one row in the result with an empty "id".  I tried adding an extra condition in the `where` clause:

```sql
select regexp_extract(path, '/id/+([0-9]+)', 1) as "id",
       sum("count") as "request_count"
  from "access-logs"
  where __time >= timestamp '2022-01-01' and "id" != ''
  group by 1
```

But when I do that, I get this error message:

```
Error: Plan validation failed: org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException:
From line 4, column 46 to line 4, column 49: Column 'id' not found in any table
```

So it doesn't let me reference the result of the expression in the `where` clause. I could of course just copy the entire `regexp_extract` expression, but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` is an aggregated column, you would need a `HAVING` clause to filter on it.